# CI/CD: "App not installed and Package appears to corrupted" error on signed apk

Tags: android, continuous-integration, apk

"App not installed and Package appears to corrupted" error on signed apk. This is the error I see when opening the app on my mobile device (version 11). What could be the reason

The binary build was distributed from App Circle and I even changed the V2 Sign to "true".Any insight on the error would be appreciated

Comment: Check the signing certificate.

Comment: The same app works perfectly if it is taken locally with the same signing certificate

The app level build.gradle file has the below in the SigningConfigs
' v2SigningEnabled true
 v1SigningEnabled true'